# Why does Mathematica take too long time to integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to evaluate a triple integral. But, the proccess of evaluating is taking too long. I waited for 3 hours, but unfortunately no result was given. What is this cause? Is it my computer or did I enter the code incorrectly?

My code is:

```
Expr=1/(8(-1+Exp[b*Sqrt[J*(2d+J*(3-Cos[kx]-Cos[ky]-Cos[kz]))*(3-Cos[kx]-Cos[ky]-Cos[kz])]])*Pi^3*Sqrt[J*(2*d+J*(3-Cos[kx]-Cos[ky]-Cos[kz]))*(3-Cos[kx]-Cos[ky]-Cos[kz])])

Integrate[Expr,{kx,-Pi,Pi},{ky,-Pi,Pi},{kz,-Pi,Pi}]
```

I wrote this in Mathematica 11.

Who can help me?

Comment: Do the parameters b and J represent arbitrary complex numbers? If not, try adding appropriate assumptions.

Comment: b and J are not comlex numbers. How do I add assumption? Can you give me information further?

Comment: For adding assumption execute: `?Integrate` and read in  Documentation,by the way I doubt there's a closed form for the integral.Dont expect every integral to have a nice closed form,maybe not even exist.One way to solve is numerically using `NIntegrate`

Answer (score 1):

Play with the following.

```
NIntegrate[Expr /. {b -> 2, J -> 3, d -> 1}, {kx, -Pi, Pi}, {ky, -Pi, Pi}, {kz, -Pi, Pi}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 5, Exclusions -> {Cos[kx] == 1, Cos[ky] == 1, Cos[kz] == 1}]
```

> 0.0031748